# Java - Looping cannot find for array of object

Tags: java, arrays, loops, oop

I just make supermarket program and initialize the object from the class using array of object like this

```
swalayanTinyV2 sw[] = new swalayanTinyV2[3];
    sw[0] = new swalayanTinyV2("Kevin", "3812345678", 5000000, 240898 );
    sw[1] = new swalayanTinyV2("Sandra", "5612345678", 6000000, 240899);
    sw[2] = new swalayanTinyV2("Ryan", "7612345678", 7000000, 240897);
```

then I make an iterate to find which object that similar to customer name and PIN.

```
int limit = 3;
for (int swalayanTinyV2 sw1 : sw) {
    while (limit!=0) {
    System.out.print("username : ");
    String username = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("PIN      : ");
    int pin = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();

        if (username.equalsIgnoreCase(sw1.getCustName()) && pin==sw1.getPin())  {

        sw1.displayMessage();

        System.out.println("MENU    : ");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1. Buy Goods");
        System.out.println("2. Top Up");
        System.out.print("Input your choice : ");
        int pil = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        switch (pil) {
            case 1 :
                System.out.print("Total of price : ");
                double total = in.nextDouble();

                sw1.setTotalBelanja(total);
                sw1.getTotalBelanja();
                sw1.Struk();

                break;

            case 2 : 
                System.out.print("Add value : ");
                double topup = in.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("=============================================================");
                System.out.println("Value added  : Rp. "+topup);
                System.out.println("Your value   : Rp. "+sw1.getTopUpSaldo(topup));
                break;
                 default : System.out.println("Invalid input!");
        }


       return;
    }
        else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect username/PIN!");
        limit--;
        System.out.println("Your chance to login : "+limit);
    }
    }
        if (limit==0) {
        System.out.println("Account has been banned.");
    }
    }
```

But the iterate makes program just referred to the 1st index of array's object. (when I input username and PIN in 2nd index of array's object, it referred as invalid username/PIN).

please help.

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Try running your program (or a simplified version) on pen and paper and you should see the flaw in the logic.

Comment: Why are you using two names? A variable can only have one name.